# List certain Python files from directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a directory I can have files with extension .run1, .run2 etc, and also files with extension .pros1, .pros2 etc.

```
Lest say the list of files in directory C:\ are:
-----------------------------------------------
 1. Orders.run1
 2. Orders.run2
 3. Orders.run3
 4. orders.pros1
 5. orders.pros2
```

In Python, how can I list files that has the maximum version numbers.

Lets say from the above example, I would like see files `orders.run3` and `orders.pros2` which is of different file extension type and also have the maximum version number?

Comment: Let's say you have some code to start with. Please [edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very novice answer. The explanation is in the comments.

```
import os
import re

max_dict = {} # A dictionary to store all unique suffixes

for i in os.listdir():
    # Split the filename into 2 halves over the dot(.) and get the suffix (extension + version)
    file_suffix = i.split('.')[1]

    # Use regex to get the trailing digits and the extension (pros, run etc)
    ext = re.search('[A-Za-z]{1,}', file_suffix).group(0)
    ver = int(re.search('[0-9]{1,}', file_suffix).group(0))


    # Check the existing version of each extension in dictionary. If found, compare and update, else insert
    if ext in max_dict: 
        if max_dict[ext] < ver:
            max_dict[ext] = ver
    else:
        max_dict[ext] = ver

# Final Output
print(max_dict)
```

### Output

```
$ python ../test.py
{'log': 148, 'pros': 11, 'run': 3}
```

### Sample input used

```
$ ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 18:16 Orders.run1
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 18:16 Orders.run2
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 18:16 Orders.run3
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 18:16 orders.pros1
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 18:16 orders.pros2
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 18:51 Orders.pros11
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 19:02 alpha.log1
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 19:02 alpha.log22
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 19:02 alpha.log9
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 19:02 alpha.log99
-rw-r--r-- 1 aprusty 197121 0 Jun  4 19:03 alpha.log148
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek. This is perfect.

Comment: Glad to help. If this or any other answer helped you, do accept and upvote.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Using os.listdir('path') will give you a list containing alle the files in 'path' so you can read each string and check the version. This is pretty easy if the version number is always at the end of the string.